# CSOM SharePoint Search API filter files only

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, csom, sharepoint-search

Using CSOM Search API is there a way to filter for only files? Something similar to the following ListItem filter would be ideal:

```
ListItem.FileSystemObjectType.Equals(FileSystemObjectType.File)
```

Ex use case:

```
if (item.FileSystemObjectType.Equals(FileSystemObjectType.File))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

The only thing similar I have found in documentation would be using the filetype Keyword Query Language (KQL) filter:

```
filetype:docx
```

I'd like to avoid using that, however, as setting all the possible valid file types feels like a sloppy solution IMO. Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the below filter to limit results for documents only:

```
IsDocument:1
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly and clean solution.